# Excluding a Directory from Redirect - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Crrently I am having a problem with redirection. The problem is that I want to redirect all further category paths to 1 category.

Example:

```
example.com/news-blog/post-name/
```

and need to redirect to

```
example.com/news/post-name/
```

I've successfully finished that with the following code:

```
RewriteRule ^news-blog/([^/]+)?$ /news/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^news-blog/(.*)$  /news/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

The thing is that I want to exclude the navigation for the categories. I want to exclude the directory path for `/page/` from redirecting.

Example:

```
example.com/news-blog/page/2
```

redirects to

```
example.com/news/page/2
```

I don't want this redirect, I want to redirect only the posts and not the category archive.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RewriteCond` to check the `REQUEST_URI` before applying the `RewriteRule`.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/news-blog/page/
RewriteRule ^news-blog/(.*)$  /news/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: The RewriteCond works well and excludes the /page/ directory. But now there is another problem, the following code is also redirecting example.com/new-blog/ to example.com/news/.

I need to redirect everything after example.com/new-blog/

Comment: I've found the solution:
RewriteRule ^news-blog/page/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^news-blog/([^/]+)?$ /news/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^news-blog/(.*)$ /news/$1 [L,NC,R=301]